# Ошибки в нативном коде Java, откуда они и почему методы вообще функционируют?и вообще правильно ли функционируют

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false); 
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

то что написано выше и нативный метод thread.interrupt();  как я прочитал одно и то же.

Почему код метода thread.interrupt() с ошибками? например скрин из нативного кода https://gyazo.com/45a251a53a82a0ff371164f130b817ed  Cannot resolve symbol Interruptible  и вот еще https://gyazo.com/94fe021030b53c8959936557859e3dd6

проблема в самом андроид студио, потому что идея всё открыла без красного кода. Есть много классов где сотни  строк кода  с ошибкой Cannot resolve symbol .
 Как вылечить студию. я ее удалил и установил заново, но не помогло. Компилируется всё нормально, но это доставляет неудобства и порой кажется что программа не работает именно по этой причине

Comment: У вас проблема с IDE, у меня IDEA находит этот интерфейс.

Comment: т.е. у вас нет такого , что открываете нативный код и там очень много подчеркнутого и красного кода ?

Comment: вот справа где ползунок видно красного много , это класс потока и это не единственный класс с ошибками https://gyazo.com/5e0ca3ee12dd2c086454a24f60c99244

Comment: и правда открыл в IDEA и всё норм, пойду погуглю в чем дело или в крайнем случае переустановлю. Но заданный мой вопрос к этому думаю не относится.

Comment: но если использовать эти методы с ошибками, то всё копмилируется нормально..

Comment: всё равно напрягает это, слишком много красного кода. попробую удалить студию и заново установить. обновление не помогло .